# jshint unexpected '@' visual studio code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am new in Angular. I am using Visual Studio Code for develop my Angular project. But i have faced some unexpected jshint error, See screenshot [image]

I did following step:

1. I have install `jhint` globally in my pc.

   npm install -g jshint

Does anybody know, how to resolved this problem?

Comment: You'd want to use TypeScript language mode instead since that is what you seem to be using :)

Comment: You know that the CLI already uses tslint to check for errors jshint would find in JS code, right? Just execute `ng lint`, or install a tslint plugin in your editor.

Comment: I have disabled jshint plugin, still have same error. And TSLint already installed in visual studio code.

Comment: delete node_modules folder and run npm install again

Comment: @ santosh singh, i have reinstalled angular project but still same problem. here is my code : ng new ng5 --style=scss --routing

Comment: If you disabled jshint and have only tslint enabled then hover over the @Component decorator. It should show you message about experimental decorators. If it does then add `"experimentalDecorators": true`, into your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: I have checked "experimentalDecorators": true. and it is okay. Then i have uninstall my visual studio code and install again with no additional VSC extension. jshint is enable in VSC. Then i didn't find any error like before. May be, this issue was raised for conflicting with other VSC extension. Anyway, problem is resolved and thanks for your help.